# Bootstrap smooth scrolling to Anchor - jScript not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitters Bootstrap, I want to have smooth scrolling to my Anchors, but it won't work. This is at the end of my document, jut before the `</body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
!function ($) {
    $(function(){
        $('#running-box, #bg-car').carousel({});

        var $root = $('html, body');

        $('a').click(function() {
            var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
            $root.animate({
                scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
            }, 500, function () {
                window.location.hash = href;
            });
            return false;
        });
    })
}(window.jQuery)

</script>
```

jQuery and Bootstrap are included correctly...

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Td8Zf/

Comment: yep, it is working just fine, there was a problem with jQuery not loading properly

Comment: maybe this might help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263600/smooth-scrolling-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 0):

If you replace

```
 'a[href*=#]:not([href=#])'
```

with

```
'a[href*=#]:not([href=#]):not([href=#idname])'
```

you can prevent the smooth scrolling from working for that one specific link,